# Installing ODBC Data Source in Windows 7 for MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, datasource

Trying to add an ODBC Data Source in Windows 7 so that I can connect
Crystal Reports to my MySQL databases.

Downloaded and ran the connector from
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html

Went to Administrative Tools --> Data Sources (ODBC).

"Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" is listed in the installed drivers, but when I try
to add it as a User Data Source I get "The setup routines for the
Microsoft ODBC for Oracle ODBC driver could not be found. Please
reinstall the driver." and "component not found in Registry."

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the tab for 'system dsn', then click the 'add' button.  In the list of drivers, there should be an option for the 'MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver'.  Select this option, and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that worked once I got the 5.1 driver installed (which for some reason took three tries). Thanks. Resolved.